# Expected number of intersections of a line piece dropped on a set of random line pieces of the same length

Tags: probability

Consider line pieces of length $L$ distributed on the plane with random orientations and their centers of mass randomly distributed at a spatial density $n$. Drop another line piece with the same length on this ensemble. What is the expected number of intersection our probe line piece has with the other line pieces? Intuition, and dimensional reasoning, suggests this number will be proportional to $nL^2$. How could I prove this? Is there a prefactor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating Laplace's needle to estimate $\pi$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441646/simulating-laplaces-needle-to-estimate-pi)

Comment: @Xi'an The questions are clearly related--but not the same.  BeMuSeD: dimensional reasoning starts by establishing a suitable unit of measure.  We might as well select $L=1,$ in which case $L$ drops out of the picture entirely.  Thus, *provided you express the spatial intensity $n$ in units of $L^{-2},$* the answer had better not depend on $L$ at all!

Comment: @whuber: I prefer to say that dimensional reasoning starts by identifying quantities which are *in*dependent of the unit measure such as $n L^2$, the so-called dimensionless groups. Indeed, if one takes $L$ as the unit of measure, then $L$ does not appear explicitly, as it is absorbed into the now dimensionless $n$, but for real-life applications, such as the one which inspired my question, the explicit form is often useful.

Answer (score 2):

This reduces to a simple case of [Buffon's Needle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem).  Let $\mathcal L$ be the last segment dropped onto the plane.  It determines two translations:

1. $\sigma_{\mathcal L}$ moves the plane a distance $L$ orthogonal to $\mathcal L;$
2. $\tau_{\mathcal L}$ moves the plane a distance $L$ parallel to $\mathcal L.$

The union of all the translates $\sigma_{\mathcal L}^m\tau_{\mathcal L}^n\, \mathcal L$ for integers $m,n$ is a set of parallel lines $\mathbb L$ spaced by $L:$ the setting of Buffon's Needle problem.  Thus, when there are an average of $\rho$ centers of mass per $L^2$ area, the rate at which the initial random segments intersect one of these parallel lines is $2\rho/\pi.$

The translates $$\mathbb{L_2} = \{\sigma_{\mathcal L}^m\tau_{\mathcal L}^{2n}\,\mathcal L \mid m, n\in \mathbb Z\}$$ (with even powers of $\tau$) occupy half of these lines and the omitted half are just the $\tau$-translates of $\mathbb{L_2}.$  In this figure, $\mathbb{L_2}$ is drawn in solid gray while $\tau\,\mathbb{L_2}$ is drawn with dashes.  $\mathcal L$ itself is shown in red, with the translations $\sigma$ and $\tau$ shown as vectors.

[image: Figure]

Since the random line segment process is homogeneous (in location and orientation), we may view it as a process on the torus $\mathbb{Z}^2 / \sigma\tau^2.$  The problem concerns the rate at which the random line segments intersect (the image of) $\mathcal L$ in this torus.

But because the chance that any line segment intersects both $\mathcal L$ and $\tau\,\mathcal L$ is zero, *the rate of intersection with $\mathbb{L_2}$ is half the rate of intersection with $\mathbb{L};$* that is, it is $\rho/\pi.$

Comment: How can I refer to this beautiful proof?

Comment: If you mean refer to this post, just click on the "cite" link at the end.

Comment: I really meant a formal citation in a paper I am working on.

Comment: That is what the "Cite" button provides.